# Good recipe for a 'line numbers' like functionality

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I have to add line numbering to my application (C++/CLI - .net2.0) which is a code editor for specialized programming language.

The problem is in a performance of my solution. I did it like this, for every textChanged event of my _rtbCode control this function is fired:

```
void DocumentElement::SetupLineNumbersCount() {
    StringBuilder ^builder = gcnew StringBuilder();
    if(_tbLineNumbers->Lines->Length > _rtbCode->Lines->Length) {
        for(int i = 0; i <= _rtbCode->Lines->Length;) {
            if(i != 0) builder->Append("\r\n");
            builder->Append(++ i);
            builder->Append(".");
        }
        _tbLineNumbers->Text = builder->ToString();
    }
    else if(_tbLineNumbers->Lines->Length < _rtbCode->Lines->Length) {
        builder->Append(_tbLineNumbers->Text);
        for(int i = _tbLineNumbers->Lines->Length; i < _rtbCode->Lines->Length;) {
            builder->Append("\r\n");
            builder->Append(++ i);
            builder->Append(".");
        }
        _tbLineNumbers->Text = builder->ToString();
    }
}
```

Where _tbLineNumbers is a TextBox where line numbers are put.
This is soooo slow (I've compared this with some other code editors). I tried to paste couple lines (around 10000) and I have huge delay of reaction.

(I already checked [How to print line numbers for textbox in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871944/how-to-print-line-numbers-for-textbox-in-c-sharp))

Comment: Do you need the line numbers to appear in the code file? Also does your programming language have code block delimeters?

Comment: No, line numbering is only as a decoration - not included to a code file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it be better to update the line number TextBox on Scroll/Resize events of the code TextBox?

This way, you'd only need to care about the visible set of lines, and typing in the code window wouldn't require a refresh of the line numbers.

[GetFirstVisibleLineIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.getfirstvisiblelineindex%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[GetLastVisibleLineIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.getlastvisiblelineindex%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

These may help you out too!

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as you've guessed is that, you're running that code on every text changed event, which will occur for more that text being added or removed. It also occurs if text colour is changed!

I would suggest that you take a more prosaic view.

You only really need to check for `System.Environment.Newline` characters and even then only when text is added programatically e.g. copy, paste, file open etc. Otherwise you could check for Keypress event to determine whether a return or enter key has been pressed (as these insert newline characters into the text).

If line numbers aren't required within the code file itself and are only for the editing view then I would suggest that you create a new, read only text window on the side of the editor window. Tie them together on scroll position using a "newline event" and automatically populate the line numbers as a newline is added. You can then save your edited code easily without having to remove the line numbers.

Alternatively, make it so that the line numbering takes up the first 4 characters of every line (as an example) with code starting at position 7. Again only calculate a line number when a newline event occurs automatically adding the line number and following 3 spaces.

Comment: there is no problem to handling a 'writing numbers' on each TextChanged event, I need that to, and I chack if a line number changed or not. When I put a large amount of text that event is called only once, so this is realy not a problem.
I think that I will try to pay attention at 'which lines are displayed' and, depending on that, build a list of line numbers in an additional TextBox (only for those which are displayed). I think that writing line numbers in the same RichTextBox where is code is not a good decision - to many complications.